# Create variable from file text in MS-DOS 6.22 batch file

Tags: batch, ms-dos

This doesn't work, for example:

```
set var=<text.txt
```

It can be done like this in BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=$(cat text.txt)
echo $variable
```

Comment: why do you need to use DOS? It has very limited capability even compared to cmd.exe. No for loop at all, for example

Comment: `set /P var=<text.txt` in `cmd` although I don't know whether `/P` is valid switch in MS-DOS.

Comment: It doesn't work @JosefZ